# Quite apart from

Tags: phrases

What does "Quite apart from the times" mean in the following sentence:

> Quite apart from the times, I have had to take tests at various points in my life.

Does it mean

1. Indicating taking tests rarely and with long gaps between tests?

   or
2. Taking tests regularly and also at special occasions?

Comment: Could you provide some more context? As it is it seems to be meaningless and would require some pretty special context to give it meaning.

Comment: _**Those archetypes in the examination halls**
In my 20 years of being part of a system that administers these tests, quite apart from the times I have had to take them at various points in life, there have been some interesting observations, while in an examination hall, and the “types” of learners who do attempt to make it through those tests_ 

This is what the full context is..

Comment: Your cited text looks like a supplementary clause (including an erroneous comma) that could be part of a complete sentence such as: *"I spend a lot of time questioning my abilities, quite apart from the times I have had to take tests at various points in my life"*.

Comment: I agree including comma is erroneous, could you please explain in what way "quite apart from the times" relating "I spend a lot of time questioning my abilities" with "I have has to take tests at various points in my life" ?

Comment: it means, 'apart from my current circumstances'

Comment: Unlike your string, "Quite apart from the times I have had to take tests at various points in my life, there have been other informal appraisals I've been subjected to." makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have inserted an extraneous comma, and this is one of the instances where punctuation is not helpful but vital. *Quite apart from the times* is meaningless: *Quite apart from the times I have had to take them at various points in my life* in your context means "Even without considering all the tests I have had to undertake (rather than invigilate or mark)".

For future refernce, please edit the context into your question rather than commenting: comments are transitory, and nobody could possibly answer this without seeing the full context.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote that the full context is:

> In my 20 years of being part of a system that administers these tests,
>   quite apart from the times I have had to take them at various points
>   in life, there have been some interesting observations, while in an
>   examination hall, and the “types” of learners who do attempt to make
>   it through those tests

In this context "quite apart from" means "ignoring" or "not taking into account". Metaphorically, what is happening is that the writer is separating out those times when they took the tests themselves and putting them aside, in a separate place, to be ignored "quite apart from" the things which the writer is considering which remain in front of them.

There is an extra wrinkle here. When "quite apart from" is used as a fixed phrase like this there is the additional implication that the writer believes that the things they are setting aside would also add weight to their case, but that they are choosing not to do so because maybe they are more debatable, tangential, controversial, or what-have-you.